# Find the radius $r$ of the figure below

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

Foe reference: Find the radius $r$ of the figure below where $D, F$ and $G$ are points of tangency and $AC = 5$ and $AB = 12$.(S: $r=4$)
[image]

My progress:

$\triangle ABC: BC^2 = \sqrt{5^2+12^2} \therefore BC = 13$

H is the center of the larger circle so:

$BH = \frac{13}{2} = 6,5\\
\triangle BIH \sim \triangle BAC \implies \frac{13}{6,5} = \frac{5}{HI} \therefore HI = 2,5\\
\triangle CKF \sim \triangle JKE \implies \frac{5-r}{JE}
= \frac{r-KE}{KE}=\frac{r-KJ}{KJ}\\
\triangle BJD \sim\triangle BAC \implies\frac{12}{5} = \frac{12-r}{r-JE} $

???

[image]

Comment: Consider the right triangle with hypotenuse $EH$ and "horizontal" and "vertical" legs. ... Interestingly, the radius is a multiple of the right triangle's inradius. I wonder if there's a way to make this obvious.

Comment: $GEH$ is a straight line, that may be helpful.

Comment: @peterwhy Thanks, but I still couldn't solve

Comment: @peterwhy In fact, the ped question to prove that r = b + c - a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $EH$ and its "horizontal" and "vertical" components,

$$\begin{align*}
(GH-r)^2 &= (AI-r)^2 + (r-HI)^2\\
(6.5-r)^2 &= (6-r)^2 + (r-2.5)^2\\
6.5^2 - 13r + r^2 &= 6^2 - 12r + r^2 + r^2-5r + 2.5^2\\
0 &= r^2 - 4r\\
r &= 4
\end{align*}$$

Comment: thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

$r = 2\overline{IH}$ = is the side of the square FOAD

Lem de Verriers: $I$ is the incenter of $\triangle ABC$ and is the midpoint of $\overline{FD}$

Inradius $\triangle ABC$:

$2r_{ABC} +a = b+c\implies 2r_{ABC}+13 = 12+5\\
\therefore r_{ABC} =2 \\
\therefore r = 2r_{ABC} = 4$

(By:Palacios)

[image]